# Access MS outlook using JAVA

Tags: java, api, com, interface, outlook

I want to create a JAVA application which will access my MS Outlook and download attachments from some received mails. I can not access the MS Exchange server directly and thus I plan to connect to local copy of MS Outlook installed on the machine, and then access the folder and mails from there.

The problem is I can not get any good open source libraries to connect to outlook frommy java application.
After a lot of research I found it can be done using [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/files/latest/download), but it looks like an old library and I am not sure whether I should use it. 
Any suggestions/ideas to get it done? I am not allowed to connect to Microsoft Exchange Server directly so JAVAMAIL is of no use..:(
I also got this [code snippet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/forums/forum/375945/topic/3822393) but I can't make anything out of it.

Comment: JACOB is open source, so it can't hurt to take a peek at the source code and see how they do it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: yeah,my only concern was it's kind of old(obsolete?).. so there might be any other way to do it?...JACOB is my last option..

Comment: Have you tried this [JOC](http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/) ?

Comment: @wodong: yeah found it during my research, can only use opensource libraries....and also did not like the installation stuff...:\

Comment: JACOB is the best (and free) option I have tried. All other COM/ActiveX solution need installation or just don't work.

Comment: Finally did it using JACOB....:))

Comment: Why can't you access the Exchange server directly?

Comment: The only non-MS software I know of that can connect is the Evolution mail client. http://www.go-evolution.org/MAPIProvider/Design

Answer (score 2):

Aspose.Email also be helpful, but it is **not** open source. I have not tried the outlook part of it though.
http://www.aspose.com/java/total-component.aspx